# how to force yaml-cpp not to excape double qoutes when insertimg with R"("some")"

Tags: yaml-cpp

i want to store a sting in a yaml file with the necessary double qoutes around it.
when i do so it stores it in a escaped way with backslash.

I need it this way:
imagePullPolicy = "Always"

it stores it this way:

imagePullPolicy ="Always"

I tried it this way
node["imagePullPolicy"] = R"("Always")";
with no success

I also tried ist with putting a char[] directly with the char representing the double quote directly but the "node" always escaping the double quote

Is the even pissible to tell the node that i want to not escape the string i want to store?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.